# Adding Array of values to a multidimentional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to add values from a `$secondArray` to `$firstArray`:

```
$firstArray = [
    0 => [
        'prodID' => 101,
        'enabled' => 1,
    ],
    1 => [
        'prodID' => 105,
        'enabled' => 0,
    ],
   ];
```

The `$secondArray` will always have the same amount of array items and will be in the same order as the `$firstArray`:

```
$secondArray = [34, 99];
```

This is what I have tried but I keep getting the wrong `stockQT` values after the exercise:

```
foreach ($secondArray as $value) {
    foreach ($firstArray as &$firstArray) {
        $firstArray['stockQT'] = $value;
    }
}
```

Incorrect Result for a `var_dump($firstArray)`:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'prodID' => int 101
      'subscribed' => int 1
      'stockQT' => int 99
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'prodID' => int 105
      'subscribed' => int 0
      'stockQT' => int 99
```

I have looked at similar posts but cant seem to get the correct vales after using different suggestions like `while()` loops. Below is what I need the `$firstArray` to look like:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'prodID' => int 101
      'subscribed' => int 1
      'stockQT' => int 34
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'prodID' => int 105
      'subscribed' => int 0
      'stockQT' => int 99
```

Comment: You want to loop through both arrays at once and then just add/merge the second array's values to the first one.

Comment: Try `foreach($firstArray as $k=>$v){$firstArray[$k]['stockQT'] = $secondArray[$k];}`

Comment: @Rizier123:  No need to loop through both _The $secondArray will always have the same amount of array items and will be in the same order as the $firstArray_

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, problem resolved!

Answer (score 1):

You just need one `foreach()` using the key since `$secondArray` will always have the same amount of array items and will be in the same order as the `$firstArray`.  Notice the `&` to modify the actual value in the array:

```
foreach($firstArray as $key => &$value) {
    $value['stockQT'] = $secondArray[$key];
}
```

Or alternately loop `$secondArray` and use the key to modify `$firstArray`:

```
foreach($secondArray as $key => $value) {
    $firstArray[$key]['stockQT'] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Just a side-note. The concept of looping was difficult enough for OP so I would advise against referencing `&$value` unless you add `unset($value);` after the loop completes.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the first option and added a unset at the end. Much appreciated!